# Understanding git workflow

Tags: git, gitorious

I need your help to understand a workflow read on this post: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

I just don't understand how to implement this one using for example gitorious. If i've a single repo with N branches but I can set permission per repository, that said what about the N branches permissions(develop, master, release ...)? If i give commit(push) permission to "Jon Doe" on that "central" repo than He will also be allowed to push to master, release branches!Am i right? So...

1. Are the "branches" in that post need to be implemented as separeted repository?
2. If Yes, than we can use branches on local repository, but can we have remote repository linked to a branch or they will be visible for all branches?

Even if all the workflow is absolutely clear, it just lack of examples of implementation.

Comment: That isn't how permissions work in Git. You can't do permissions by branch.

Comment: The git flow model is more controlled by policy than technology. If John Doe can't be trusted to follow your policy and not commit directly to master, then don't give him write access to your repo. Let him clone it and send you patches or pull requests.

Comment: @meagar of course i know i can't do permission on branch that's why I opened this question.

Comment: @AlexHowansky mhm....so your solution is to keep a user as integration manager of the "central" repo, and so everydeveloper should send a pull request even for pushing into development right?

Comment: No, every developer should have write access and be trusted to follow the rules. :) I.e., "don't commit to master" is defined by department policy, not software hooks.

Comment: @AlexHowansky if I trust every developer then if we "hire" juniors developers i must give them the same trust policy. But I need a secure architecture that give the chance to insert new devs on the fly and prevent push/merge (that have not followed the workflow policy) errors, fix push errors could be a pain in the ....
So the question, what's the best to **enforce a workflow**, create many "central" repositories, or only one with many branches?

Comment: You don't want many central repos, that's counter to the very essence of a distributed system like git. Give full write access to your trusted developers and use pulls to merge from the rest.

Comment: Ok, googlin around and keep thinking i just merged the workflow proposed in the post with the integration model. So everyone of us will have a remote copy of the main repository to work with and where we can start merge request.
Last thing, in this workflow If I finished a feature(in branch) i need to push the branch into my personal remote repo or i need to first merge the branch into my local repository and then push into my personal remote? I'm sorry if is not clear :P